# How to create a multithread system on tcp/ip?

Tags: c, multithreading, server, client

I have this system of client-server and I need to multithread. The are TCP/ip ,and I dont now how to start the threads, so I can have many clients to send a msg on server. Please help me.

I can accpet also and a simple client server system with no ip. For to eun the code is go

```
gcc server.c -o server 
./server 1234
gcc client.c -o client 
./client 127.0.0.1 1234
```

Server code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
//#include "header.h"
#define SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv [])
{
    int psock, sock,cli_addr_len,table[10][10],i,j,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,res1,res2;;
    char msg[SIZE];
    struct sockaddr_in addr,cli_addr; // Internet socket
    char reply[SIZE];
    
    memset(&cli_addr, 0, sizeof(cli_addr));
    cli_addr_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET; // Internet socket
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // All interfaces
    addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv [1]) ) ;
    psock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Stream socket
    bind(psock, ( struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    listen (psock, 1) ;

    strcpy(msg,"") ;
    printf("\nwaiting for new connection (port : %s) ...\n", argv [1]) ;
    sock = accept(psock, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &cli_addr_len);
    printf("connection established...\n");


    recv(sock, msg, SIZE, 0) ;
    printf("the msg is : %s ",msg);  
     
     close(sock);
     close(psock);
     unlink(argv [1]);
      return 0;
}
```

Client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "header.h"

#define SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv [])
{
    int sock, i=1 ;
    char msg[SIZE],reply[SIZE];
    struct sockaddr_in addr; // Internet socket

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET; // Internet socket
    inet_aton(argv [1], &addr.sin_addr);
    addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]) ) ;
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Stream socket
    connect(sock, ( struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    
    strcpy(msg,"") ;
    strcpy(reply,"") ;
 
     fgets(msg,sizeof(msg),stdin);
        send(sock, msg, strlen(msg) + 1, 0);

      close(sock);
    return 0;   
     
     }
```

Comment: 1) learn about threads 2) use threads

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Put `accept` into a `while(true)` loop and create a new thread for each new connection. Pass `sock` to that thread and do all the work in that thread. If you have a problem with that, you need to show what have you tried to introduce threads and where you are stuck, There should be tons of examples for tiny HTTP servers out there that could serve as an example for handling multiple connections.